# I want to learn on how to build iOS apps using phonegap in a windows laptop?

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to learn how to create ios apps using phonegap but I'm not sure if it's possible to create ios apps via phonegap+windows? (I'm currently a student, Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help and be very much appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some projects like "Marmalade" to develop IOS projects on Windows but all that looked good aren't free. You should also understand, that such projects are unofficial and problems while developing can occur.

So, in my opinion - there is no way to develop IOS projects under Windows. 
But you can try to install Hackintosh like iATKOS at your laptop as a second OS and develop apps using xCode there. I've done the same on my Asus laptop.